# I keep getting a 404 error on livewire assisted input

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have been having a 404 error message on my livewire Laravel project anytime I type an input. It was working perfectly fine on localhost but was giving this error of `GET https://chat.mhminternationaltv.com/livewire/livewire.js?id=83b555bb3e243bc25f35 net::ERR_ABORTED 404` on the console.

My asset_url in Livewire.php in my config folder points to my subdomain folder
`'asset_url' => "https://chat.mhminternationaltv.com",

If I modify it to
`'asset_url' => "https://chat.mhminternationaltv.com/vendor",` I get a 404 error on any of the livewire powered inputs. With this error on the console

`POST https://chat.mhminternationaltv.com/vendor/livewire/message/customer 404`  
With details of

```
value   @   index.js:32
sendMessage @   index.js:221
value   @   index.js:231
later   @   debounce.js:8
setTimeout (async)      
(anonymous) @   debounce.js:12
value   @   index.js:204
callback    @   node_initializer.js:87
(anonymous) @   index.js:532
setTimeout (async)      
(anonymous) @   index.js:531
```

[image]

My Http/Livewire/Sale.php is

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Cart;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\User;
use Auth;

class Sale extends Component
{
    public $order, $products = [], $product_code, $message = '', $productIncart;

    public $pay_money = '', $balance = '';

    public function mount() {
        $this->products = Product::all();
        $this->productIncart = Cart::all();
    }

    public function InsertoCart() {

        $countProduct = Product::where('id', $this->product_code)->first();
         
        if (!$countProduct) {
            return $this->message = 'Product Not Found';
        }
        $countCartProduct = Cart::where('product_id', $this->product_code)->count();

        if ($countCartProduct > 0) {
            return $this->message = 'Product '.$countProduct->name. ' already exists in cart!';
        }

        $add_to_cart = new Cart;
        $add_to_cart->product_id = $countProduct->id;
        $add_to_cart->product_qty = 1;
        $add_to_cart->product_price = $countProduct->price;
        $add_to_cart->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        // $add_to_cart->user_id = 0;
        $add_to_cart->save();

        $this->productIncart->prepend( $add_to_cart);

        $this->product_code = ' ';
        return $this->message = "Product Added Successfully!";
        // dd($countProduct);
    }

    public function IncrementQty($cartId)
    {
        $carts = Cart::find($cartId);
        $carts->increment('product_qty', 1);
        $updatePrice = $carts->product_qty * $carts->product->price;

        $carts->update(['product_price' => $updatePrice]);
        $this->mount();
    }

    public function DecrementQty($cartId)
    {
        $carts = Cart::find($cartId);
        if ($carts->product_qty == 1) {
            return session()->flash('info', $carts->product->name. ' Quantity cannot be less than 1, add quantity or remove product from cart!!!');
        }
        $carts->decrement('product_qty', 1);
        $updatePrice = $carts->product_qty * $carts->product->price;

        $carts->update(['product_price' => $updatePrice]);
        $this->mount();
    }

    public function removeProduct($cartId) {
        $deleteCart =  Cart::find($cartId);
        $deleteCart->delete();

        $this->message = "Product removed from cart!";

        $this->productIncart = $this->productIncart->except($cartId);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        if ( $this->pay_money != '') {
            $totalAmount = $this->pay_money - $this->productIncart->sum('product_price');
            $this->balance = $totalAmount;
        }
        return view('livewire.sale');
    }
}
```

My views/livewire/sale.php is

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="animated fadeIn">
        <!-- Sales Table -->
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5>Sales</h5>
          </div>
          <!-- <form action="{{ url('/new-sale') }}" method="post">{{ csrf_field() }}       -->
          <div class="card-body card-block">
          <div class="my-2">
              <form wire:submit.prevent="InsertoCart">
                <input wire:model="product_code" type="text" id="" name="" placeholder="Scan Product Barcode here" class="form-control">
            </form>
          </div>
          @if (session()->has('success'))
          <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">{{ session('success') }}</div>
          @elseif (session()->has('info'))
          <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">{{ session('info') }}</div>
          @elseif (session()->has('error'))
          <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">{{ session('error') }}</div>
          @endif
          <!-- {{ $productIncart }} -->
              <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th colspan="6">Total</th>
                    <!-- <th>
                      <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success add_more"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                    </th> -->
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="addMoreProduct">
                    @foreach($productIncart as $key=> $cart)
                  <tr>
                    <td class="no">{{ $key + 1}}</td>
                    <td width="30%">
                      <input type="text" value="{{ $cart->product->name }}" class="form-control">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="number" value="{{ $cart->product->price }}" class="form-control">
                    </td>
                    <td width="15%">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                          <button wire:click.prevent="IncrementQty({{ $cart->id }})" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"> + </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                          <label for="">{{ $cart->product_qty }}</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                          <button wire:click.prevent="DecrementQty({{ $cart->id }})" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"> - </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="number" value="{{ $cart->product_qty * $cart->product->price }}" class="form-control total_amount">
                    </td> 
                    <td>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" wire:click="removeProduct({{ $cart->id }})"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  @endforeach
                </tbody>
              </table><br>
              <form action="{{ url('/sales-cashier') }}" method="post">{{ csrf_field() }}
              @foreach($productIncart as $key=> $cart)
                      <input type="number" hidden value="{{ $cart->product->id }}" name="product_id[]" class="form-control">
                      <input type="number" hidden value="{{ $cart->product->price }}" name="price[]" class="form-control price">
                      <input type="number" hidden value="{{ $cart->product_qty }}" name="quantity[]">
                      <input type="number" hidden value="{{ $cart->product_qty * $cart->product->price }}" name="total_amount[]" class="form-control total_amount">
              @endforeach
                <div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <h3>TOTAL: <b>{{ $productIncart->sum('product_price') }}</b></h3>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="number" wire:model="pay_money" class="form-control" id="paid_amount" name="paid_amount" placeholder="Amount Paid">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="number" wire:model="balance" class="form-control" id="balance" name="balance" placeholder="Change" readonly>
                    </div> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-auto d-flex justify-content-around">
                      <div class="p-2 flex-fill">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block">
                            SELL
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="p-2 flex-fill">
                        <button type="button" onClick="PrintReceiptContent('print')" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark btn-block"><i class="fa fa-print"></i>
                            Print Receipt
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- </form> -->
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Sales Table -->
    </div>
</div>
```

My **routes.php** is

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['frontlogin']], function () {
    Route::match(['post', 'get'], '/', 'frontController@index');

    Route::match(['post', 'get'], '/sales', 'frontController@addSale');

    Route::post('/sales-cashier', 'frontController@store');

    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/settings', 'UsersController@updatePassword');

});
```

My Controller

```
class frontController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('index');
    }

    public function addSale() {
        $products = Product::all();
        $sales = Sale::all();

         //lastorder
         $lastID = Transaction::max('customer_id');
         $receipts =  Sale::where('customer_id', $lastID)->get();
        
        return view('sales.new_sale')->with(compact('products', 'sales', 'receipts'));
    }
    
    public function store(Request $request) {
        //return $request->all();

        DB::transaction(function () use ($request){

                $customers = new Customer;
                $customers->name = "customer";
                $customers->save();

                $customer_id = $customers->id;


            for ($product_id = 0; $product_id < count($request->product_id); $product_id++) {
                
                $sales = new Sale;
                $sales->customer_id = $customer_id;
                $sales->product_id = $request->product_id[$product_id];
                $sales->quantity = $request->quantity[$product_id];
                $sales->price = $request->total_amount[$product_id];
                $sales->save();
            }

            $transactions = new Transaction;
            $transactions->customer_id = $customer_id;
            $transactions->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            // $transactions->user_id = 0;
            $transactions->total = $request->paid_amount;
            $transactions->save();

            Cart::truncate();

            
            $products = Product::all();
            $sales = Sale::where('customer_id', $customer_id)->get();
            $orderedBy = Customer::where('id', $customer_id)->get();

           
        });

        return back()->with('success', 'Sale successfull. Please print your receipt!');
        
    }

    public function receipt(){
        return view('sales.receipt');
    }
}
```